# repeat each vector's values based on random values in an interval range

Tags: r

I have this data

```
 data <- c("h", "H", "homme", "masculin", "f")
```

I want to repeat each values based on random values in an interval range

What I Tried :

```
 dummy <- rep(data, ceiling(runif (1, 1, 3)))
 sort(dummy)
```

My results :

```
"f"        "f"        "h"        "h"        "H"        "H"        "homme"    "homme"    "masculin" "masculin"
```

What I expected : each value can be repeat randomly in a range

I can expect  : 2 "f", 3 "homme", 1 "masculin"
or
I can expect 1 "f", 1 "homme", 3 "masculin"
...

Comment: What is `test`? Did you mean `data`?

Comment: Yes, sorry for my mistake. I edited my post.

Comment: @bouncyball that either gives 2 of everything or 3 of everything

Comment: reptime <- sapply(1:length(data),function(x) x <- ceiling(runif(1, 0, 3)) ); dummy <- rep(data , reptime ); sort(dummy)

Comment: maybe `unname(unlist(mapply(rep, a, sample(3, 3))))`? Gives a warning about lengths but It shouldn't bother you as per R's recycling capabilities (??)

Comment: I agree. I have no problem with this warning

Comment: @maydin it works . do you want to convert to answer?

Comment: @sotos what is a?

Comment: sorry, I meant `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach...

```
   reptime <- sapply(1:length(data),function(x) 
    x <- ceiling(runif(1, 0, 3)) ); 

    dummy <- rep(data , reptime ); 

    sort(dummy)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use `mapply` to `rep` vector `data`, `sample(3, 3)` times.

**NOTE** That it will give you warning

> Warning message:
>   In mapply(rep, data, sample(3, 3)) :
>
> longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter

However, It shouldn't worry you because it will recycle the `sample` vector in which case all the recycled values will again be in your predefined range, thus satisfying your conditions, i.e.

```
unname(unlist(mapply(rep, data, sample(3, 3))))
#[1] "h"        "H"        "H"        "H"        "homme"    "homme"    "masculin" "f"        "f"        "f"       

 unname(unlist(mapply(rep, data, sample(3, 3))))
#[1] "h"        "H"        "H"        "homme"    "homme"    "homme"    "masculin" "f"        "f"       

unname(unlist(mapply(rep, data, sample(3, 3))))
#[1] "h"        "h"        "H"        "H"        "H"        "homme"    "masculin" "masculin" "f"        "f"        "f"
```